# "No BoundingBox" error in latex

Tags: graphics, include, bounding-box

This is my preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,french]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx} \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=3.17cm,right=3.17cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx} \usepackage{caption}
```

This is how the image is inserted in the document

```
\begin{figure}
\center
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figures/liver-foci-bioassay-01.png} 
\caption{Protocole expérimental pour l'essai décrit par pour l'étude
de la carcinogénicité du foie à moyen-terme \citep{Ito:1995vn}} 
\label{fig:ito1} \end{figure}
```

This error appears every time I try to compile in Latex

> ! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in
>   figures/liver-foci-bioassay-
>   01.png (no BoundingBox). See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H  for immediate help.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you compiling with `latex.exe`? If so, please switch to `pdflatex.exe` as you are importing PNG file.

Comment: Well, I am using TexMaker and I usually compile with a "quick compilation" option. However when I add citations I have to compile in latex and I get this error. Though, it doesn't seem to change anything in the document.

Comment: Make sure the quick compilation  uses `pdflatex.exe`.

Comment: I have just tried with pdflatex I don't see the error. I thought it was something really important but apparently it's not. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Hmm... It is a confusing confirmation. :-)

Comment: The "No bounding box" usually means LaTeX can't get the figure (not there, format unsupported).

Comment: I had never seen that error before, or at least I had never paid attention to it.